# trying to learn how to define methods in a new object

Tags: javascript

I've done a lot of reading about using objects in js and this is one of the techniques that I found for creating an array of objects and defining a method within each:

```
function myObj(){
        this.dCount = 0;

        this.myMethod = function(){
            dCount = 1;
            console.log(dCount);
        }
}

var objects = new Array();

function loadObjs(){

        for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            var myObj = new Object();
            objects[i] = myObj;
        }

        objects[0].myMethod();
}
```

However, this (and all the other techiques I've tried) returns `objects[0].myMethod is not a function`.

I still don't get it.  Can someone please help?

Comment: Use block codes when doing this kind of multiline codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are instanciating a generic object, not your own.

Try this:

```
objects[i] = new myObj;
```

Answer (score 1):

#### You haven't instantiated!

Replace:

```
var myObj = new Object();
objects[i] = myObj;
```

With:

```
objects[i] = new myObj;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are instanciating `myObj` variable as an `Object` class not a `myObj` class.

```
function myObj(){
        this.dCount = 0;

        this.myMethod = function(){
            dCount = 1;
            console.log(dCount);
        }
}

var objects = new Array();

function loadObjs(){

        for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            // var myObj = new myObj();
            // objects[i] = myObj;
            // this is better to separate the variable name from class name. so:
            var m = new myObj();
            objects[i] = m;
        }

        objects[0].myMethod();
}
```